# Volume of an truncated elliptical cone

Tags: conic-sections, volume

Is there a general expression for the volume of an truncated elliptical cone, that is a cone in which both the base surface and top are elliptical and not circles? Both of the ellipses are parallel surfaces if that helps. I have managed to find a general expression for a normal truncated cone at $[\frac π 3(r_1^2+r_1r_2+r_2^2)h]$. Would it be possible to approximate by using the average volume of 2 normal truncated cones calculated by using the 2 sets of radii in the ellipses?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!

Comment: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa2013/Kar/EMAT%206690/Essay%202/Frustum.pdf